# Java game data transfer

Tags: game-engine

Does anyone know how to transfer data from website (SQL/PHP) to PC game. For example, like MMO games, one buys items in website and updated items in game. I am trying get an idea how it works.

Thanks

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. I suspect the answer is along the lines of "they share a database."

Comment: It is broad indeed because I dont know where to begin or start